# Image getWidth and getHeight returning -1 inappropriately

Tags: java

Why does this:

```
URL url = MinecraftPlatformGame.class.getResource("images/diamondPick.png");
image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url); 
int width = image.getWidth(null);
int height = image.getHeight(null);
System.out.println(width);
System.out.println(height);
```

Return `-1` for both the `width` and the `height`

Edit: My question before I figured out the answer was actually how I was supposed to fix it.
I fixed it by doing the following:

```
URL url = MinecraftPlatformGame.class.getResource("images/diamondPick.png");
image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url); 
MediaTracker mTracker = new MediaTracker(this);
  mTracker.addImage(image,1);
        try {
            mTracker.waitForID(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MinecraftPlatformGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
int width = image.getWidth(null);
int height = image.getHeight(null);
System.out.println(width);
System.out.println(height);

url = MinecraftPlatformGame.class.getResource("images/gui.png");
image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
  mTracker.addImage(image1,2);
        try {
            mTracker.waitForID(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MinecraftPlatformGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        width = image1.getWidth(null);
height = image1.getHeight(null);
System.out.println(width);
System.out.println(height);
```

Problem I have now is this doesn't seem very efficient nor does it seem like I should need so much code just for two images to be imported and given sizes. Is there a better more efficient and easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Javadoc:

> If the width is not yet known, this method returns -1 and the
>   specified ImageObserver object is notified later.

In response to your edit, and following Russell's comment, use `ImageIO.read()` instead to get a fully-loaded image.

Comment: An alternative is ImageIO.read(), which always returns a fully loaded image.

Comment: Okay I updated my question with the mediatracker which now returns the correct width and hegiht yet seems inefficent considering that is only for TWO images yet there will be plenty more. I'm assuming there is a better way to import a photo as a resource and get widths and heights in a better way. @RussellZahniser

Comment: All you need is `image = ImageIO.read(url)`. Then `image.getWidth()` will be correct from the start, with no need for MediaTracker.

Comment: @RussellZahniser okay the way you stated worked, though I had to surround it with a try and catch block.

Comment: A simple approach is to make a new `BufferedImage` twice as big, get its `Graphics2D` with `createGraphics()`, and paint the original image into it, doubling the size. You can control the scaling algorithm by setting the `KEY_INTERPOLATION` rendering hint on the `Graphics2D`. If you are processing a lot of images, it helps to `dispose()` each `Graphics2D` when you are done with that image.

Comment: @RussellZahniser I guess I removed my comment to late but I figured it out before I saw this answer. All I did was add two extra int's to the drawImage: `g.drawImage(image, 200, 200, width*2, height*2, this);` And that resized it.