# java.awt.Image getWidth and getHeight methods not working well?

Tags: java, image, height, width

I'm trying to display images which happen to be instances of the Image class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html).
I need to have it a BufferedImage and I found a piece of code that works well for that purpose (using Graphics).
However to create the BufferedImage I need to know the width and height of the image. The Image class does have getWidth and getHeight methods but they don't seem to work properly all the time. Using debug I found out that sometimes, the width and height were set to -1. I also found out that actually calling getWidth and getHeight methods "updates" the width and height value, so the height and width have correct values after then. So I added a fake "image.getWidth(null)" before calling getWidth and getHeight "for real" and got the right values.
That works fine when I do it in debug mode and step by step, BUT it doesn't work well anymore when I run it normally. I added a "Thread.sleep(5);" after the "fake" getWidth call and it made it work.

This behaviour is quite weird and maybe someone would have an explanation and/or a way to make it work without that sleep trick ?

Edit:
this is how the image is loaded :

```
URL url = "path/to/img";
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
```

I have let's say read-only access to this code, this is why I'd like to start from there to get my BufferedImage.

What I added to this is

```
image.getWidth(null); // "Fake" call to force the image to update his width&height
try {
Thread.sleep(5);
} catch...
if(image.getWidth(null) != -1 && image.getHeight(null) != -1) {
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();
bg.drawImage(image, 0, 0 null);
bg.dispose();
}
```

If I remove the sleep it seems that getWidth "doesn't have time" to complete and I still have width/height = -1 for some images.
Some methods used to compute the dimensions is probably asynchrone.
I understand that the ImageIO.read() is a simpler and more effective method but I'd still like to find a workaround to get this work :)

If it's not possible I'll find another way it's no big deal actually.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766477/image-getwidth-and-getheight-returning-1-but-are-not-suppose-to-be

Comment: That could solve it yes, but I would like to make this work and keep using an Image instance created from the toolkit (like in your thread). I don't really have the possibility to modify the code creating the Image (which uses the Toolkit) and replace it by an ImageIO.read... :s

Comment: But `ImageIO.read(FILE);` returns an image? So you only have to change 1 line :) . How do you actually read the image? Please add some code :) .

Comment: I edited the main post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the image isn't fully loaded yet. Try adding a [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html), add the image to the tracker and wait for the image to be fully loaded (using `waitForAll` or `waitForID`).

Answer (score 1):

A crude but effective way to wait for an image to fully load is to construct an [`ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) with it. The constructor doesn't return until the image is fully loaded. I.e.,

```
new javax.swing.ImageIcon(image); // force image to load
```